# Allow multiple middleware scopes in Laravel 8 routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to hit a route that needs to support multiple scopes for auth. It currently requires a scope called `manage-clicks-creatives`, but I would like to also allow `manage-all-clicks-creatives`. The Laravel docs seem to indicate that this is possible:

> The scope middleware may be assigned to a route to verify that the incoming request's access token has at least one of the listed scopes:

```
Route::get('/orders', function () {
    // Access token has either "check-status" or "place-orders" scope...
})->middleware('scope:check-status,place-orders');
```

> From https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#token-scopes

Here's the relevant bits from `api.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router
 */
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->group(['namespace' => 'Creatives'], function () use ($router) {
        $router->group(['middleware' => 'scope:manage-clicks-creatives,'], function () use ($router) {
            $router->post('creatives', 'CreativeController@store');
        });
    });
});
```

But when my test runs, with a user who has the `manage-all-clicks-creatives` scope, the request fails:

```
[2021-09-14 19:10:08] testing.ERROR: You do not have permission to do that. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Validation\\UnauthorizedException(code: 0): You do not have permission to do that. at /lumen-api/src/Http/Middleware/AuthorizeScope.php:23)
```

[stacktrace]

I've tried comma-delimited scopes:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'scope:manage-clicks-creatives,manage-all-clicks-creatives'], function () use ($router) {
```

And pipe-delimited

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'scope:manage-clicks-creatives|manage-all-clicks-creatives'], function () use ($router) {
```

and scopes with arrays:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => ['scope:manage-clicks-creatives', 'scope:manage-all-clicks-creatives']], function () use ($router) {
```

But none of them seem to work.

Comment: The documentation notes methods for checking all listed scopes or any listed scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#check-for-all-scopes, and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#check-for-any-scopes (difference is `scope:` vs `scopes:` keyword), might be something with that? Sidenote, I haven't worked with Scopes in Passport, so I can't say with certainty what the issue is here. At a glance, your first approach _should_ work

Comment: in method handle your middleware add variable $scope

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $scope) {

$scopes = explode('|', $scope);
dd($scopes);
}

next in your route

Route::get('/orders', function () {
    // Access token has either "check-status" or "place-orders" scope...
})->middleware('scope:check-status|place-orders');